# How would I write a regex that matches the values following a string (to the next comma)

Tags: javascript, regex, csv, key-value

I have a csv of key=value pairs.  How do I write a regex that matches only the value "1234$32@a" (or any value following the key "password") without using lookbehind?

```
system=blah, user=stevedave, password=1234$32@a, mylocation=amsterdam
```

I have tried the following:

```
[\n\r].*password=\s*([^\n\r]*) didn't match anything (from another SO thread)
\bpassword=\s+(.*)$            just plain ol' wrong.
\bpassword=.+\b,               matches the whole string password=1234$32@a,
(?:password=)(.+,)\2           not sure I understand backreference correctly
```

It appears my system doesn't support lookbehinds (and they're too expensive anyway), so that's not an option.  Is there another way?

Comment: I should've mentioned that it's javascript Regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match anything other than whitespace or `,` after `password=`:

```
var kv = 'system=blah, user=stevedave, password=1234$32@a, mylocation=amsterdam',
    re = /password=([^\s,]+)/,
    match = re.exec(kv);
alert(match[1]);
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/bE4bZ1/1

Strictly speaking, if you want anything up to the next comma, that can be `[^,]`.

Comment: That's close, but still includes the "password=" part of the kv pair.  I *just* want the "1234$32@a" part.

Comment: updated the answer to show you how it might be used in javascript

Comment: javascript.  I was using regexr.com to test.  It appears it may be inferior to regex101.com.  I'll test in a script.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick (I don't know which special characters you might allow, so I specified only the ones in your example):

```
(?:password\s*=\s*)([A-Za-z0-9@$]+)
```

[Please see Regex 101 demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/vB8sJ3/1)

Comment: That works, but in javascript regex, it still matches the whole string.  Is there a way to force "password=" to a non-capture group for js regex?

Comment: I am not following you. It *is* in a non-capture group.

Comment: I thought so, too, but for some reason it was showing up as part of the match.  Is it the tool I was using?:

http://regexr.com/3aeac

Comment: Try Regex 101 instead with the Javascript option (follow link in my answer)

Comment: Better yet, try it in your JS :)

Answer (score 1):

A common pattern in Javascript, with its infamous lack of lookbehinds is

```
.replace(/.*(stuff you're interested in).*/, "$1")
```

for example:

```js
str = "system=blah, user=stevedave, password=1234$32@a, mylocation=amsterdam"

pwd = str.replace(/.+?password=(.+?),.+/, "$1")
document.write(pwd)
```

`.exec` or `.match` followed by `[1]` are fragile because they fail if there's no match. `.replace` just returns the original string.